# How can I get user displaynames who posted comments with Firestore v9 in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'am using Firestore v9 and i try to get users comment with onsnapshot After i reach the datas i try to get user displayname who commented. I can pull the data without any problem, but it doesn't render.

Here is my useEffect Function

```
useEffect(async () => {
setLoading(true);
const datas = [];
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
  query(
    collection(
      db,
      'workspace',
      currentWorkspace,
      'pages',
      activeDecision.id,
      'ideas'
    ),
    orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  ),
  (querySnapshot) => {
    const snapData = querySnapshot.docs.map(async (snap) => {
      const userRef = doc(db, 'user', snap.data().user);
      const user = await getDoc(userRef);
      datas.push({
        id: snap.id,
        idea: snap.data().idea,
        user: snap.data().user,
        displayName: user.data().displayName, // <---
      });
    });
    setIdeas(datas); //<-- no problem everything seems good.
    setLoading(false); //<-- loading false for rerendering  
  }
);
return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Here is my return func.

```
return (
!loading &&
 (
  <Wrap spacing="30px">
    {ideas?.map((item, index) => (
      <WrapItem key={index}>
        <Stack p="4" boxShadow="base" borderRadius="sm" maxW={'265px'}>
          <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
            <Avatar
              size="sm"
              name={item.displayName.toLowerCase()}
              cursor="pointer"
            />
            <Text fontWeight="semibold">{item.displayName}</Text>
          </Stack>
          <Stack
            direction={{ base: 'column', md: 'row' }}
            justifyContent="space-between"
          >
            <Text>{item.idea}</Text>
            
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </WrapItem>
    ))}
  </Wrap>
)
```

);

The interesting thing is that after this snapshot, when I removed userRef and user, react rendering perfectly. So the problem may be occurring because I'm pulling data from another collection after onSnaphot.

```
 const userRef = doc(db, 'user', snap.data().user);
 const user = await getDoc(userRef);
```

How can I use onSnaphot then get datas from different collection ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    databaseUrl: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

**user.js**

```
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { collection, addDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
export const getuser = async () => {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "user"))
        return querySnapshot
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);

    }
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getuser } from './user.js'
export default function Home() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        let data = await getuser()
        let users = []
        data.forEach(doc => {
            users.push(doc.data())
        })
        setUser(users)
    }, []);
    return (
     <div>
      {user.map((item, index) => (
          <div>
          <p>{item.displayName}</p>
          <p>{item.idea}</p>
          </div>
       ))}
      </div>)
}
```

Comment: Hey Meet thanks for your answer but it looks like you're only getting the user collection data. The problem stems from not being able to pull the displayname from the users collection with the userId data in the comments collection in onsnaphot function.

Comment: Send me the screenshot of firebase database

Comment: First check the output of first query in the console, after that check if the second query works.